# How to detect a SSIS package component type in SSISDB?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2017

I have a SQL, which helps to analyse every SSIS package component duration, it uses

- SSISDB.catalog.executions
- SSISDB.CATALOG.operations
- SSISDB.CATALOG.event_messages

The fact is, I can't understand from data in this entities, what does `event_messages.message_source_name` stand for. I have only its name and its path in package.
I need to understand every component type:

- SQL Script Task
- Data Flow
- Sequence container
- Loop container
- and so on

For example, I have a SSIS package (name = "Test") with 4 components:

1. Execute Sql Task (name = "Start")
2. Data Flow Task (name = "Load")
3. Script Task (name = "Check")
4. Execute Sql Task (name = "Finish")

And querying SSISDB I want to get something like this

```
Package_name |Component_name | Component_type
Test         | Start         | Execute Sql Task
Test         | Load          | Data Flow Task 
Test         | Check         | Script Task
Test         | Finish        | Execute Sql Task
```

Is it possible?

Comment: What do you mean by "you need to understand every component type"? As in what they are? I don't follow what you're really asking here.

Comment: I' ve edited my question, providing example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The fact is, I can't understand from data in this entities, what does event_messages.message_source_name stand for.

It describes object name, defined in `Name` property, which generated this message record. Together with `message_source_id` it allows to identify source of the message. I.e. in your case it can be the name of the package or name of the task or container or dataflow.
Based on the event log information, you can only distinguish between the following objects:

- Package
- Task
- Container
- Data Flow Task

Good news - this table is filled on Standard logging level.

There is no easy way to get component type from SSISDB. To get component type you need to analyze package source code. The problem is that it is stored encrypted in `internal.packages`. You can [export](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/25913.import-a-ssis-project-from-catalog-using-t-sql-script.aspx) the whole project which contains the package you are interested in with `catalog.get_project` SSISDB stored procedure, and then unzip it and read XML source of the referred package. By using `message_source_id` GUID you can identify task in XML and read its type.

Comment: Thank you, I’ll wait for a while for some other answers, if there is no other option, will mark your answer as correct.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are after the view below:

> catalog.execution_component_phases

```
use SSISDB  
select package_name, task_name, subcomponent_name, execution_path,  
    SUM(DATEDIFF(ms,start_time,end_time)) as active_time,  
    DATEDIFF(ms,min(start_time), max(end_time)) as total_time  
from catalog.execution_component_phases  
where execution_id = 1841  
group by package_name, task_name, subcomponent_name, execution_path  
order by package_name, task_name, subcomponent_name, execution_path
```

If view is empty then set the logging level of the package execution is set to Performance or Verbose.

More information:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/system-views/catalog-execution-component-phases?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: It's a pity, this view seems to be empty.

Comment: The catalog.execution_component_phases view provides this information when the logging level of the package execution is set to Performance or Verbose.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your answer, this only shows data flow info. So this will help me to understand, what package component is data flow.
What about other component types?